# Using IUIAutomation functions

Tags: c++, function, user-interface, pointers, ui-automation

I'm new to UI Automation and was trying to implement it in my application.
I Created a IUIAutomation** object and initialized it using this code:

```
InitializeUIAutomation(iUiAutomation);

HRESULT Control::InitializeUIAutomation(IUIAutomation **ppAutomation)
{
    return CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(ppAutomation));
}
```

Now, I have no idea though how to use the functions of IUIAutomation with a IUIAutomation** object..

I've tried

```
iUiAutomationElement  = **iUiAutomationVariable.ElementFromHandle(parentWindowHandle);
```

and

```
iUiAutomationElement = *iUiAutomationVariable->ElementFromHandle(parentWindowHandle);
```

but both didn't get recognized..

And with

```
iUiAutomationElement = IUIAutomation::ElementFromHandle(parentWindowHandle);
```

it tells me "a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object"

How exactly are you using the IUIAutomation pointer? The official documentation mentions all the functions and what they do but no specific examples..

Hope someone can help

Comment: the first two things you tried are right, but that function takes 2 arguments not one. `(*iUiAutomationVariable)->ElementFromHandle(parentWindowHandle,iUiAutomationElement); `

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the brackets around *iUiAutomationVariable which was why it didn't recognize the ElementFromHandle function either